# Sumifs with array condition wont work if one of the criteria on the array isn't in the table

Tags: excel

Let's say you have the following table:

[image: TABLE]

And you have the following conditions:

[image: conditions]

And you want the sum of COL2 when COL3 equals 1 and it respects the conditions presented above.

The result of the following function returns zero (even with shift + enter):

[image]

But, if I remove the f3 line from the conditions table, it works.

Couldn't find anywhere on the internet a workaround this without using VBA.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Just to check, do you want the sum of B when A is a,b or x and C is 1 and D is f2 or f3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have two sets of multiple 'OR' conditions in SUMIFS or COUNTIFS, one of them has to be a row and the other one has to be a column [as explained here](https://exceljet.net/formula/sumifs-with-multiple-criteria-and-or-logic)

So you would need to change your formula to

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,F2:F4,D:D,TRANSPOSE(G2:G3),C:C,I2))
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer, Tom. Thank you very much!